# Command line application xcode with core data pathForResourse always returns nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, command-line-tool

I've created a command line application through xcode with core data. But when I do this:

```
NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"json"];
```

`dataPath` is always nil. I have a file next to the `main.m` file called test.json and I **have** added it to the Build Phrases -> Copy Files section. It is next to `main.m` also in Finder.

I'm using OSX Mavericks and xcode 5. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out after some fiddling. Apparently you have to check not only **Products Directory** in the **Copy Files**  section, you also have to un-check **Copy only when installing**, also take care of the subpath, so you don't miss that.